# Facebook: The message could not be posted to this Wall

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have some legacy FBML applications on Facebook.
The share buttons are generated by FBML tag. i.e.

```
<fb:share_button>
```

As I share content using the button, it shows:

> Could not post to Wall
>
> The message could not be posted to this Wall.

Does anyone know if there any changes from Facebook that makes the button not working anymore?
Facebook is no more supporting FBML?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue -- sharing some links to a particular site post just fine, but others result in the "The message could not be posted to this Wall." error.

Comment: any solution for this because i am ev1 stuck in this